# Cant connect to SQL DB via ConnectionString but can via ssms

Tags: c#, sql-server, permissions

There are and remote sql server and local C# app.

I can connect to DB via ssms
The command
'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe" -S server -U user -P password '
performs great

**But in code**

my ConnectionString:

connectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=DB;integrated security=false;User ID=user; Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

when I try to open connction

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
```

I get an error
"Cannot open database "DB" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user '*user*'"

How can it possible? I have managed to connect by using the same user&pass to this server via ssms!! 
What other permission should have sql-user to connect to DB via C#-application?

P.S The point is (99.9%) on DB server side. And some permissions on it. Because with another remote Server everything works ok.

Answer (score 0):

By default SSMS connects to the database ***Master***, but your App try to connect to the specific Database. Perhaps you haven't sufficient rights for connection to specified Database.
Try to connect to server using SSMS with following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe" -S server -d DB -U user -P password
```

Where the DB is your database name from connection string.